# Why does my rand() number come up as 0?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

This is a function member of a class I'm making and it doesn't cause any syntax errors only a semantic error. The random number it's supposed to make comes up as 0.

```
int Warrior::attack()
{

int hit = 0;

 switch (weapon)
{

case 6:
     hit = rand() % (5 - 1 + 1) + 1; 
     break;

case 7:
     hit = rand() % (10 - 4 + 1) + 4;
     break;

case 8:
     hit = rand() % (15 - 9 + 1) + 9;
     break;

case 9:
     hit = rand() % (20 - 14 + 1) + 14;
     break;

case 10:
      hit = rand() % (25 - 19 + 1) + 19;
      break;
 }

std::cout<< "You hit " << hit <<"!\n";

 return hit;
}
```

Please Help!
Thank you,
~katana

Comment: Is `weapon` in the range [6,10]?

Comment: Seems to not do that [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c399ff4136dc80a1abd91a998acbdaf4). Realize that you've defined `hit` to be 0 if no case matches are found.

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes (there will be 6 weapons in the game a bronze sword is represented by 6).

Comment: Don't use hardcoded numbers for weapon indexes, use `enum`.
Also, i recommend you to make a function `getRand(int a, int b)` to generate the `rand() % (a - b + 1) + b` line. :) Just for the better expierence.

Comment: @katana7070 Print `weapon` and I think you might be surprised.

Comment: How do you know what value `rand()` is returning? And are you calling `srand()`?

Comment: @sftrabbit ok i printed weapon but nothing showed up?!? How can that be, i have weapon set to 6 when i created the warrior object and i have it in the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the lack of a `default` switch statement, i.e. `weapon` not triggering any `switch` clauses.

Try:

```
 switch (weapon)
{

case 6:
     hit = rand() % (5 - 1 + 1) + 1; 
     break;

case 7:
     hit = rand() % (10 - 4 + 1) + 4;
     break;

case 8:
     hit = rand() % (15 - 9 + 1) + 9;
     break;

case 9:
     hit = rand() % (20 - 14 + 1) + 14;
     break;

case 10:
      hit = rand() % (25 - 19 + 1) + 19;
      break;
default:
      throw std::exception("switch statement failed");
 }
```